# How to set the value of a column based on other column

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have the following schema:

```
customer(cid,cname), 
books(isbn,price) 
orders(oid,cid,isbn,odate,quantity,value)

1. A customer can purchase any no.of books on a single order on the same date
2. A customer can purchase any no. of different types on a single orders
3. A customer can place multiple orders on a same day
```

So, when a customer place order for isbn say 121,141 whose prices are 500,500 respectively, of quantity 2,5 respectively, the column 'value' must be filled with 1*500=500 and 5*500=2500 respectively. 
So the value column must be quantity*price always. How can I specify this during the creation of orders table? Should I need a trigger?

Comment: You should avoid using term `schema` in this context when talking about Oracle. `Schema` has special meaning in Oracle, basically it is all objects that belong to particular database user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your model: your `orders` table refers to the `books` table via the `isbn` field, when an order can contain several books !
I would add an intermediate table:

```
single_order(sid, oid, isbn, quantity)
```

referring to the `orders` one via the `oid` field. An item of `orders` would then be the sum of the items of `single_order` having the corresponding `oid`. And the `value` field would then be the sum of the `price` of `books` by the `quantity` of `single_order`, you can easily link to these 2 tables with joins.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks!